# Where can I find a list of all ng directives and their priorities

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Every angularjs directive has a priority, which defines the order at which the directive is compiled when it co-exists with other directives on the same element. ([See here for details](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-))

However, I was searching for a list/reference of all ng directives (i.e. directives in the default ng module), sorted by their respective priorities. I found nothing in the angular docs. Can someone provide such a list, or a link to such a list?

Comment: You can check in the documentation of respective directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look on the latest code (1.3):

- 1200: `ngSwitch`, `ngSwitchWhen`, `ngSwitchDefault`
- 1000: `ngNonBindable`, `ngRepeat`
- 600: `ngIf`
- 500: `ngController`
- 450: `ngInit`
- 400: `ngInclude`
- 100: `ngList`, `ngValue`, `option`, `ngMinlength`, `ngMaxlength`, `ngMin`, `ngMax`, `ngPattern`
- 99: `ngHref`, `ngSrc`, `ngSrcset`
- 1: `ngModel`, `select`
- 0: Everything else

But, in most cases, you don't need to bother with these, as long as you remember that `ngIf` and `ngRepeat` are high up there.